# Error when trying to select with comma separated lists

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I need to get the data shown from a mysql db. The code below I think presents what Im trying to do but the execution is definitely wrong. What do I need to change to get this to work?

```
SELECT 
up.model AS style,
up.list_price AS price,
GROUP_CONCAT(t1.name) AS colorlist,
GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS sizelist,
nr.title,
nr.body AS description,
FROM 
uc_products up,
(SELECT c.name FROM uc_attributes a 
       JOIN uc_product_options b ON (b.nid = a.nid) 
       JOIN uc_attribute_options c ON (c.oid = b.oid AND c.aid = 6) 
       WHERE a.nid = up.nid) AS t1,
(SELECT c.name FROM uc_attributes a 
       JOIN uc_product_options b ON (b.nid = a.nid) 
       JOIN uc_attribute_options c ON (c.oid = b.oid AND c.aid = 9) 
       WHERE a.nid = up.nid) AS t2
LEFT JOIN node_revisions nr ON (nr.nid = up.nid)
```

The Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM uc_products up, (SELECT c.name FROM uc_attributes a JOIN uc_product_options' at line 8

Comment: What's actually happening when you run this? Consider adding a small example with expected output and either actual output or the error, if you're getting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the comma before `FROM`. Try this:

```
SELECT 
up.model AS style,
up.list_price AS price,
GROUP_CONCAT(t1.name) AS colorlist,
GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS sizelist,
nr.title,
nr.body AS description
FROM 
uc_products up,
(SELECT c.name FROM uc_attributes a JOIN uc_product_options b ON (b.nid = a.nid) JOIN uc_attribute_options c ON (c.oid = b.oid AND c.aid = 6) WHERE a.nid = up.nid) AS t1,
(SELECT c.name FROM uc_attributes a JOIN uc_product_options b ON (b.nid = a.nid) JOIN uc_attribute_options c ON (c.oid = b.oid AND c.aid = 9) WHERE a.nid = up.nid) AS t2
LEFT JOIN node_revisions nr ON (nr.nid = up.nid)
```

Comment: OH GEEZ, when mysql gives you errors they always give you the text just after the error. I was going nuts looking at FROM wondering what was causing the error and somehow I missed that comma. thankyou very much.

Comment: You're welcome. I did it so many times, that now I can spot it instantly :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma after 'AS description' that needs removing.